# Cannot complete trac installation because python-genshi is missing

Tags: svn, trac, opensuse

I try to install [**trac**](http://trac.edgewall.org/) on my suse root server. So first I installed all svn packages using yast. After that I searched for python in yast in software management because I have to intall following packages

apache2-mod-python

lib-xml2-python

python

python-devel

**python-genshi**

python-setuptool

python-tk

python-xml

pyxml

But python-genshi is not listed there. It is missing. How do I install it? Because when I try `easy_install trac` I get following error:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done what it says? `mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` and try again.